# Orbit of the identity matrix under Lie group algebra actions

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

I would like an explicit description of $\mathbb{R} SO(n) I_n$, i.e., the image of the identity under the action of the group algebra of $SO(n)$ by left multiplication. Equivalently, what is an explicit description of the vector space $\{\sum_i c_i A_i: A_i \in SO(n)\}$? Presumably this is well-known and in the context of all compact simple Lie groups? I need this to understand some continuous state space Markov chain of particle systems.

Edit: to those who vote to close, please state reason. If you have a one-liner answer, why not give it a shot? I will close it myself when I see a satisfactory response.

Comment: The question isn't clear to me.   What is the precise action here, and are you just referring to the group algebra of the abstract group?

Comment: @Jim: yes just the usual left multiplication action. So the question is really asking for the vector space spanned by $\sum_i c_i A_i$, where $A_i \in SO(n)$. I will clarify in the text. 

Comment: @John: Unless I'm missing something subtle, the "natural" group action on the underlying vector space is irreducible and thus the resulting matrices should span the whole space. Is there more going on? 

Comment: It is the sum of $n$ copies of the natural actio
n, so it is not irreducible. 

Comment: One simple remark is that the vector space spanned by the orbit $Gp$
always contains the vector space $\mathfrak g\cdot p$, where the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ is acting by the derived representation.


Comment: @Jim: I am actually referring to the action on the space of $n\times n$ matrices. So for instance when n=2, the vector space spanning by $\mathbb{R}SO(2)$ acting on $I_2$ is simply $\mathbb{R}I_2 \oplus \mathbb{R} J_2$, which is not the full $M_{2 \times 2}$. Hope this clarifies a bit. I could be hallucinated..

Comment: @Claudio: thanks! That's pretty much as far as I could get, and for $n=2$ that's handy.

Comment: @John: Sorry, I didn't understand what you meant by "the action" here, since I took it to be just left multiplication in the matrix algebra.   

Comment: @Jim: No problem. I am glad ppl here helped me understand the actions on matrices, which is crucial for my study of the Kac random walk. See for instance: http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.1539

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n\geq3$, it is the full space of $n\times n$ real matrices. The reason is that 
the $SO(n)$-orbit through the identity is the same as the $SO(n)\otimes SO(n)$-orbit by left
and right multiplication, $(g,h)\cdot X=gXh^{-1}$, and this representation is irreducible for $n\geq3$. (Note that the span of any orbit is an invariant subspace, in general).

Comment: Why doesn't this work for $n=2$? Is real irreducibility not good enough?

Comment: For $n=2$ you have a $2$-torus $T^2$ acting on $\mathbf R^4$, and any real irreducible representation of a torus is $2$-dimensional, so $\mathbf R^4$ splits as $2$ irreducible $T^2$-components $\mathbf R.I\oplus \mathbf R J$. Here I am talking about real representations and real dimensions.   

Comment: On the other hand, for $n\geq3$, $SO(n)$ is compact semisimple. If $G$, $H$ are compact semisimple and act irreducibly on $U$, $V$, resp., then $G\times H$ acts irreducibly on $U\otimes V$ by the 
tensor product representation.


Comment: In your case, the tensor product representation $\mathbf R^n\otimes\mathbf R^n$ is equivalent to acting by left and right multiplication
on $M(n,\mathbf R)$. 

Comment: Sorry, in my comment above I meant that $\mathbf R^4$ splits into 
$2$ irreducible $T^2$-components, which are $\mathfrak{so}(2)$ and the traceless symmetric $2\times2$ matrices. 

Comment: @Claudio:thanks a lot for the clarification! I now appreciate semi-simplicity more.

Comment: John: it is a pleasure to see applications of Lie groups going on. 